# Redirects to Keycloak

Tags: c#, keycloak, openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0

Help me figure out Keycloak. I have a pure ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project.
I need to enable authorization and authentication via Keycloak.

For this I use OpenIdConnect.

Code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    //Sets cookie authentication scheme  
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(cookie =>
{
    cookie.Cookie.Name = "keycloak.cookie";
    cookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    cookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{ 
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/ipn";
    options.ClientId = "IpcpAuth";
    options.ClientSecret = "Tns4Rli7UvsP72pkqqmOrIIBcEG6whVA";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "https://schemas.scopic.com/roles"
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44311/";
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});
```

The project has a basic Home controller. If you place the attribute `[Authorize]` to the entire controller, then redirection occurs to Keycloak and after successful authorization, normal reverse redirection does not occur.

My screen is dark and the page is reloading in a cyclic manner.

You can put an attribute on a controller method that opens a new page.
Then the project opens and when you click on the button that calls the method, the keycloak authorization window opens. After authorization, a redirection occurs to the home page, and not to the page that the method should open.

As a result, it is impossible to go to that page; the redirect always returns to the home page.

If I indicate here such an address

```
context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44311/Home/Privacy"
```

Then when you switch to the controller method, cyclic loading begins again after authorization

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`? According to the docs you'll overwrite the path which gets called for the keycloak signin. Maybe thats causing the cyclic call.

I do have a project with working keycloak auth, and I did not have to set this parameter. Instead I adjusted my login page to include a redirect-parameter and called the keycloak challenger like this:

```
public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri = "/") {
    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri });
}
```

In the `App.razor` I then redirect to this login including the redirect URI:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            if (context.User == null) {
                var returnUrl = UriHelper.ToBaseRelativePath(UriHelper.Uri);
                UriHelper.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
            } else {
                @:Not authorized!!!!
            }
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

If you don't explicitly set a return URI, make sure to set the `Home URL` in the keycloak client. Also make sure your redirect URLs are inside the `Valid redirect URIs`-field in the keycloak client (something like `https://localhost:44311/*` in your case probably).

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic reloading is caused by `cookies not sticking`. The Microsoft defaults (for compatibility reasons) use `SameSite=None` when cookies are set. This requires a secure connection on a developer workstation and is also a suboptimal cookie setting for deployed systems. See if updating to these settings progresses your setup:

```cs
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
                
    // Use the strongest setting in production, which also enables HTTP on developer workstations
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {

    // Use the same settings for temporary cookies
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```